# SQL Pull the latest datediff for each Category

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. 
Repair - 
RepairID, EquipID, RepairDate

Events -
EventID, EquipID, ReturnDate, CustomerID

I am trying to determine who the last customer was that returned the equipment, before the repair was done. Equipment could have been returned multiple times in the past, but I only need to track the very last customer that returned it.

Final result will include CustomerID, EquipID, ReturnDate, RepairDate

My SQLFiddle for a sample DDL and query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2691/6/0

This returns all the customers, not only the very last one that returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that return what you expect?

Option 1:

```
SELECT E.EquipID,
    E.CustomerID,
    max(E.ReturnDate) MAXRETURN
FROM Repair R
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY EquipID ORDER BY ReturnDate DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM Event E
    WHERE R.RepairDate > E.ReturnDate
        AND E.EquipID = R.EquipID
    ) E
WHERE E.RN = 1
GROUP BY E.EquipID,
    E.CustomerID
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT E.EquipID,
    E.CustomerID,
    max(E.ReturnDate) MAXRETURN
FROM (
    SELECT E.*,
        row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY E.EquipID ORDER BY E.ReturnDate DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM Event E
    INNER JOIN Repair R
        ON E.EquipID = R.EquipID
    WHERE R.RepairDate > E.ReturnDate
    ) E
WHERE E.RN = 1
GROUP BY E.EquipID,
    E.CustomerID
```

Comment: This is exactly it! I have never used CROSS APPLY on my queries. Mainly because I have to work on different DBMS so in order to avoid confusion between different systems, I try to find the cross compatible version. My only challenge at this point is federation between DB2 and SSDS. The Events table is on DB2, while the Repair is on SSDS.

Comment: I think some engines would allow you to refer Repair from within a JOIN subquery (instead of CROSS APPLY), but SQL server cries (so that is not cross platform too). Another idea is to encapsulate the entire join within a subquery and only keep the WHERE and GROUP by in the outer query (i.e. no cross apply and no parent table reference) ... that looks more promising from portability perspective ... and it might happen to be faster.

Comment: AUCH ... and there is an error - E.EquipID=R.EquipID is missing ... will fix it in a minute.

Comment: I should probably use another post for this, but what if there is more than one repair for that same equipment, and I would want to return the record for customer before the recent repair? I modified my DDL adding another repair for EquipID 100 but it would still only return the two records from before.

Comment: Please see my changes, previous version was not OK (I added E.EquipID = R.EquipID). I also added option 2 that should be more portable. With regards to repairs - you can add one more row number on RepairID (and play with ordering) if you only want to show the a single repair out of multiple (and filter by that new row number). If you want to see them all you can try adding the RepairID in the PARTITION BY so that you have your RN restarted for each Equipment & Repair combination.

Comment: Yep, adding RepairID, or RepairDate to the PARTITION BY works to get unique row number. I appreciate you going far and beyond in clarifying the code and simplifying even further with alternate solution. Thank you!!